# Server to server Communication behind a load balancer

Tags: iis, load-balancing

I have two IIS servers sitting behind a load balancer. And my application's DNS is app.domain.com. I should have a way to communicate from one server to other server without touching load balancer. Application in both servers is listening to port 80. Also I have more than one application deployed in same port in these servers. How can I refer to (URL) to individual servers without using DNS.

Comment: Via their private IPs?

Comment: i have multiple application deployed on same port. how can i refer to a specific application ?

Answer (score 0):

Use IP:port with HOST header to distinguish between multiple applications in each node.